# Xfce4 hibernation not waking up properly in debian stretch

Tags: debian, xfce, hibernate

When I run `xfce4-session-logout --hibernate` it seems to work. However, it fails to recover the session and starts up as a normal reboot (yet slower).

Hibernation works both with the commands

```
 "systemctl hibernate" and "s2disk" (I manually installed uswsusp).
```

I see two possible ways forward:

1) Fix the `xfce hibernation`

2) Make `xfce` use either of the other two hibernation commands

However, I failed at both.

Comment: 1) Do you have a swap partition? 2) Did you have a swap partition at the time you installed Debian?

Comment: I do have a swap partition - in particular s2disk uses it properly. I don't recall/know how long the swap partition has been there - I suppose it could have been created by uswsusp when I installed it, but somehow I doubt that and assume it was there from the beginning.

Comment: Install `pm-utils` package and use `pm-hibernate` command , see [`man pm-action`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/pm-utils/pm-hibernate.8.en.html)